# cannot access the data inside an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, fetch

I'm having trouble accessing data inside my state which I fetch from my database,
this is my state:

```
state = {
    inputDataArr: [],
    inputDataArrTest: [
      {
        formID: 'test',
        inputArr: [1, 2, 3],
        labelArr: [4, 5, 6]
      }
    ]
  };
```

this is the collection I'm importing from the database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ba96b8ebffd923734090df4"
    },
    "inputArr": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
    ],
    "labelArr": [
        "label1",
        "label2",
        "label3"
    ],
    "formID": "5ba96b83bffd923734090df0",
    "__v": 0
}
```

which is an object with 2 arrays in it,
this is how I fetch it :

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/api/datas')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(datas => {
        const filterdDatas = datas.filter(
          data => data.formID == this.props.match.params.id
        );
        this.setState(currentState => ({
          inputDataArr: [...currentState.inputDataArr, ...filterdDatas]
        }));
      });
  }
```

now when I console log inputDataArr and inputDataArrTest I get an array with an object inside,
 exactly the same,
 but when I console log InputDataArrTest[0] which is what you can see in my state    I can see the arrays and the formID,
 but when I console log inputDataArr[0] I get undefined, really frustrating, anybody knows why?

Comment: Where are you doing the `console.log`? In the `render` method? There will always be a first render without the async data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping and doing data manipulation inside the render is never a good idea and isn't easy to debug.

My suggestion is to initialize the state to an empty array, and call a method to return the mapped data.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        inputDataArr: []
    };
}

render() {
    const data = this.state.inputDataArr.map(...)
    return <div>{data}</div>
}
```

This way state is initiated before first render and `data` will return an empty array.
After `componentDidMount` the state will update and will re-render with the new data.

As a side note, i would do the mapping in a third `then` and set the state to the result itself.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where are you running the `console.log` but `setState` has a callback method that you can run after the actual data has been updated:

```
this.setState(currentState => ({
  inputDataArr: [...currentState.inputDataArr, ...filterdDatas]
}), () => {
    // this is the callback for setState, you can access the updated data
  console.log(inputDataArr);
});
```

**Note** If you run the `console.log` in `render` keep in mind that the first `render` call will always run before the async data has been fetched.

**Note #2** [Do not use `componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) at all and especially not for fetching data.
[Use `componentDidMount` instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Comment: thank you for your comment,  I copied your code and changed to DidMount and still I get inputDataArr is undefined

Comment: `inputDataArr` is `undefined` or `inputDataArr[0]` is undefined?

Comment: yes I posted  a solution that worked for me thanks to another stack overflow post, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you test `filteredDatas` before using `...filteredDatas` ? Maybe it is not an Array and result to other thing or an empty Array.
2. Are you sure `this.props.match.params.id` is defined and equal to the `formID` property?
3. If it exists only one object with unique `formID` why don’t you use `Array#find` instead of `Array.filter` and then update your state with

   this.setState(prevState => ({
       dataArr: filteredDatas ? prevState.dataArr.concat([filteredDatas]) : prevState.dataArr // Here with Array#find, filteredDatas is null or a object not an Array
   });

Answer (score 0):

```
 renderLabels() {
    const { inputDataArr } = this.state;
    return (
      !!inputDataArr.length &&
      inputDataArr[0].labelArr.map((label, index) => (
        <th key={index}>{label}</th>
      ))
    );
  }
```

conditional rendering solved my problem

Comment: also, debugging it will be hell

Comment: `.length` will never be `-n` so its either `0` or above. hence there's no reason to coerces to a Boolean. `inputDataArr.length && ...`  should be enough. By the way, your question lacks a lot of important details (such as your `render` method)